# Write to XML-File

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a special Problem.

I'm loading a `XML` File from Web with different tags like `<job_id>`.
These `XML` Data is written to a file named `xmlInformations.xml`.
Every Information is loaded from file to a `ArrayList<Hashmap<String,String>>` named `taskItems`

```
public void setListTaskData(String filename) {

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(readFromFile(filename));

    NodeList nodeListTasks = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TASK);

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeListTasks.getLength(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Element e = (Element) nodeListTasks.item(i);

        map.put(KEY_TASK_UUID_OBJ, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_UUID_OBJ));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_INFO, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_INFO));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_OBJECT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_OBJECT));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_LOCATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_LOCATION));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_OBJECT_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_OBJECT_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_OBJECT_SNR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_OBJECT_SNR));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_REGISTRATION_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_REGISTRATION_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_TASKIMAGE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_TASKIMAGE));
        map.put(KEY_TASKIMAGE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASKIMAGE));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_HEADLINE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_HEADLINE));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_SUBJECT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_SUBJECT));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_ACTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_ACTION));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_PRIORITY_COLOR, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_PRIORITY_COLOR));
        map.put(KEY_TASK_STATUS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TASK_STATUS));
        taskItems.add(map);
    }
}
```

They will displayed on a `ListView`.
After i clicked on an Item, it starts a new `Activity` named `SingleTaskActivity`.
This `Activity` gets the Informations by an `IntentExtra` from `TaskListActivity`.

It looks like:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //neue Oberflaeche starten
    Intent in = new Intent(this, SingleTaskList.class);;
    in.putExtra("taskItems", taskItems.get(position));

    startActivity(in);
}
```

The `SingleTaskActivity` displays now the Informations.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    Serializable xmlFileNames = i.getSerializableExtra("xmlFileNames");
    String filename = xmlFileNames.toString()+".kx_task";
    setListTaskData(filename);

    CustomAdapterTasks adapterTasks = new CustomAdapterTasks(this,taskItems);
    setListAdapter(adapterTasks);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

The User now can type something in an `Edittext` or take a Picture.

And here is the Problem:

When a User finishes his work and is clicking on the button "save" at the bottom, how can i save all these Informations into the File at the same position in that `XML` File?

I hope it's clear what my Problem is.
I'm working now about 12 Days but didn't found out how it works.

Thank you!

King Regards

Comment: I would suggest you make a utility class and post all your logic of writing and retrieving data from xml there. You can then use this utility class in activities that you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startactivityforresult()` and @`override onactivityresult` for the first Activity to save and restore position line in XML file.
For instance, read this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/1979882

Comment: It sounds like a good solution!! Can you show me how to write the text or image given by the SingleTaskAktivity to the TaskListAktivity in the same position? I hope it's clear what i mean.

Comment: Thank you until yet so much!! Do you know how i can use at last the position?

Comment: I do not understand which last position do you mean?